# gcloud commands working from command line, but not from python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I am trying to run an existing flex template using a service account. If I run the following commands on the command line, the job is started successfully:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=******.json --project=********

gcloud dataflow flex-template run ***** ...
```

Because there is no Dataflow Python client, I am trying to have a Python program run those same commands, but put them together programmatically. I have confirmed that the commands used in the program are the same as the ones I'm using on the command line - but the job fails with an authentication error. Here is the python code being used:

```
result = subprocess.run("gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=******.json --project=********", shell=True, capture_output = True, text = True)
result = subprocess.run("gcloud dataflow flex-template run ****** ...", shell=True, capture_output = True, text = True)
```

This produces the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.flex-template.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: (60c1e988debfc8c6): Current user  cannot act as service account
```

The Service account being used has "serviceAccountUser" permissions in the project where we are running the dataflow job - What am I missing? I see no errors in any of our project logs.

Comment: This command is probably failing because you did not specify the ACCOUNT (service account email address) on the command line: `gcloud auth activate-service-account`. Always check the exit status of programs.

Comment: you probably should launch both commands with one subprocess.run.

Comment: Specifying the account does not change the error, and I've confirmed that with and without the specification, the right account is listed as active

Comment: I agree launching both through one subprocess might help, but for some reason the call to gcloud auth activate-service-account cancels all commands after it

Comment: After adding everything to the same subprocess.run() with'&&' separating commands I still get the same error with a seemingle unset user

Comment: `gcloud` is not a program. It is a shell/command script that launches a Python program. `exit` is called which terminates further script execution. On Windows, you can prefix calling `gcloud` with `call`, as in `call gcloud auth activate-service-account`.

Comment: Why do you need to launch your Flex Template from a `Python` script ? What is the reason please ?